# How to align views/widgets using only java, and no XML

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I am developing an android app, where the entire UI is being developed in Java, since there's alot of dynamic stuff involved, like i might have to add buttons and checkboxes, depending on the user interaction.
I want to know how to position 2 different views relative to one another?
if i was using XML, i would've written like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...
    <EditText android:id="@+id/text1" .... />
    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1" .... />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now how do i do the same thing using Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar: [How to lay out Views in RelativeLayout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305395/laying-out-views-in-relativelayout-programmatically)

And this looks exactly like your question: [Setting parameters on child views of a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885077/relativelayout-programatically-in-android)