# what layout to use when I am adding Textview on runtime ? (android)

Tags: android, android-layout

I am adding textview on runtime and I want textview to be added on the last line or next line if it cannot fit on the last line. I am trying to use RelativeLayout . I am trying to specify params like ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT But this is not working. So, I wanted to ask which layout should I use ?

```
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.categorylayout);
    //  ll.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT );
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ll.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);  
        for(int i =0 ; i<tags.size();i++){
            TextView tt = new TextView(this);
            tt.setText(tags.get(i));
            tt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            ll.addView(tt  );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not using `params`, I believe you intended to use

```
tt.setLayoutParams(params);
```

instead of

```
tt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

However this way `TextView`s will overlap each other, so you might also want to `.addRule()` for vertical alignment inside your loop.

**edit**

```
for(int i =0 ; i<tags.size();i++){
    TextView tt = new TextView(this);
    tt.setText(tags.get(i));
    tt.setId(i+1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT); 
    if (i == 0)
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    else 
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i);

    tt.setLayoutParams(params));
    tt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    ll.addView(tt);
}
```

*brief exlpanation*: you set ids for each `TextView` (as explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5d84cbce1ab802bc),  RelativeLayout resolves only ids for each children), and so next one will be below previous. First one is aligned with parent's top. I haven't tested it, but at least it is starting point.

Comment: Do you mean example for vertical alignment?

Comment: I ment how to add a rule . I think you were telling something like this . Thanks a lot I got it working.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885077/relativelayout-programatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many widgets in your xml file,then using **LinearLayou**t with **vertical_orientaion** 
you can add it at any specified position like this:

```
ll.addView(tt,your_position);
```

Hope this will help. :)

Comment: No actually I can add two textView one the same line but if i do with this i cannot add two textview on the same line