# Give ALIGNMENT to the fields in relative layout at Runtime in android?

Tags: android, alignment

I am working to create fields at run time, like in a relative layout am adding one text field at right corner and one Check-box at the left corner.
For this am getting problem, currently i am using the following code:

```
ViewGroup hori_layout=new RelativeLayout(getParent());
            hori_layout.setLayoutParams(new   ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView tv1=new TextView(getParent());
            tv1.setText(_medContactNames[i]);
            tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

            hori_layout.addView(tv1);
            hori_layout.addView(cb);

            layout.addView(hori_layout);
```

Comment: See this 


 it will helps you


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885077/setting-parameters-on-child-views-of-a-relativelayout

Comment: Stack overflow always welcomes you...vote for my comment

Answer (score 0):

*

```
/**
     * GENERATING RELATIVE LAYOUT AT RUNTIME
     * */
    public class RL extends RelativeLayout {
        public RL(Context context,int i,String flag) {
            super(context);
            //FIRST FIELD OF THE LAYOUT
            TextView firstField = new TextView(context);
            firstField.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("LAW")){
                firstField.setText(_lawContactNames[i]);
            }else{
                firstField.setText(_medContactNames[i]);
            }
            firstField.setId(1);
            //SECOND FIELD OF THE LAYOUT
            CheckBox secondField = new CheckBox(context);
            secondField.setId(2);
            //FIRST LAYOUT WHICH MUST BE PRESENT AT LEFT END == TEXT FIELD
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpSecond = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            addView(firstField, lpSecond);
            //SECOND LAYOUT AT RIGHT END == CHECK BOX
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lpFirst = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lpFirst.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, secondField.getId());
            addView(secondField, lpFirst);
        }
    }
```

*